# Regex for -1 to 999 but can accept blank

Tags: java, regex

Regex for -1 to 999 but can accept blank

I have created this ^(?:^[0-9]+)?$ . This regex accepts positive numbers and also blank values. How do I limit it to 3 digits and allow it to accept -1 also.

I tried using the annotations @max and @min in Java . But they do not allow blank fields. I am using the annotation @pattern to match the incoming number to a regex

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this purpose?

Comment: This regex can accept either -1 , empty or 0-999 . It is a business requirement

Comment: @HeenaMittal All three of those can be achieved without regex.

Comment: For future reference, it is a good idea to describe the technical limitations that force you to use regexes (or any other tool). If you do not do that you will get questions and answers about using completely different tools that have no relevance to your question.

Comment: @Torben Or answers that perform the business requirements in a much better way; in this case, Bean Validation is the likely option.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed But I am performing validations using annotations as soon as I recieve the request payload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

```
^(?:-1|[0-9]{1,3})$
```

### Demo

But actually, I *wouldn't* use this regex if I were using a programming language.  Instead, this requirement would more easily be handled by a range check, e.g. in Java:

```
int input = 10;
if (input >= -1 && input <= 999) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

If you also want to allow blanks, then just add an empty case to the alternation:

```
^(?:-1|[0-9]{1,3}|)$
```

Comment: I tried using @max and @ min but the thing is they throw an error if  the field is empty

Comment: @HeenaMittal So when the question says *"-1 to 999 but not blank"* you actually meant, *"-1 to 999 **or** blank"*, right? If so, please **edit** the question to clarify that.

Comment: How will this regex change for -1 to 900 ?

Comment: I am guessing that the input is a `String`. Why not parse it to a `Number`? @HeenaMittal

Comment: @HeenaMittal Please don't change the question and ask for a new answer. Your question wasn't clear enough from the beginning and people have been giving you suggestions which you haven't been very responsive towards. You did receive an answer to your original question. If it solves your problem, you should accept it, then, if you have a different question, you could ask a new one but after doing your own research.

Comment: I will _not_ edit my answer, because you should not be changing your question after others have answered.  If you want a regex for -1 to 900, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I will change back my question , but can you help me with a new regex ?

Comment: @Heena Here is your other regex: `^(?:-1|[0-9]{1,2}|[1-8][0-9]{2}|900|)$`

Answer (score -1):

I use this regex for valid numbers from 1 to 999, allowing for a blank input while ensuring that the first digit is not zero.

```
^$|^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The posted question asks for a regex that accepts numbers in the range -1 to 999. Does your regex accept -1 (negative one) or 0 (zero)? I don't think so. In any case, incorrect answers are considered valid answers on SO. Note that you can either delete your answer or [edit] it. Although I did not down-vote your answer, I guess that the down-vote is because your answer does not answer the posted question.